# [ArangoDB]: Find a matching object form Java

Tags: kotlin, arangodb, arangodb-java

I want to check if an object exists in the database. I wuld like to do something like this:

```kotlin
fun <T> containsDocumentThat(matches: T.() -> Boolean, clazz: Class<T>): Boolean =
    arango.db(DbName.of(database))
        .takeIf { it.exists() }
        ?.collection(name)
        ?.takeIf { it.exists() }
        ?.readAll(clazz)
        ?.find { it.matches() }
        ?: false
```

But there is no such thing like `readAll()` or `find(class, object)` in the API.
Did someone try to do such search and succeeded?